# How to change CSS of website if accessed through a mobile browser

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown menu in the header on my website. I was messing around with the design of the dropdown menu on the mobile version of my website and it looks way better than before. (It was all the same color, now the header is an aqua light green/blue color and my dropdown menu is #333.) I went back to the desktop version and now the entire menu container is #333. But if I revert my changes, fixing the way my desktop version looks, the mobile version will go back to the original design.

Any tips on how to fix this issue. I'm not very good at JavaScript but I was thinking perhaps a code might could command that the background color stay aqua light on my desktop version and show as #333 on my mobile version.

I don't know what's best. Anyone else have an idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [CSS media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp), this is a simple way to change the CSS of your website whenever it gets below a certain width.

```
/* This will change the background-color to #333 whenever the width of the screen is below 480px */
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: #333;
    }
}
```

**Don't forget the `<meta>` tag to get the proper viewport data:**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Answered! I tried this method and it works perfectly!!! Thanks so much. I would vote you up but I don't have enough points to have access to that feature. Thanks so much!

Comment: @RustyFlick No problem at all! Please don't forget to mark my answer as the correct answer so other people can quickly find the solution if they encounter the same or a similar problem