# How to make website responsive in mobile screen

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am working on a Bootstrap project, In my project I am trying to make my website responsive to

Mobile screen also but in Mobile screen responsive is not coming. I tried a lot to make a website

As responsive. So please help me to achieve this.

This is Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 bg-danger">
              <div>
                    <ol>
             <li class="heading-li">Managing cookies
                            <p class="mt-2 paragraph">9.1. Most browsers allow you to refuse to accept cookies and to
                                delete
                                cookies. The
                                methods for doing
                                so vary from browser to browser, and from version to version. You can however obtain
                                up-to-date
                                information about blocking and deleting cookies via these links:
                                (i) https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?hl=en (Chrome);
                                (ii)https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enable-and-disable-cookies-website-preferences
                                (Firefox);
                                (iii) http://www.opera.com/help/tutorials/security/cookies/ (Opera);
                                (iv)https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/17442/windows-internet-explorer-delete-manage-cookies
                                (Internet Explorer);
                                (v) https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21411 (Safari); and
                                (vi)https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10-microsoft-edge-and-privacy (Edge).
                                9.2. Blocking all cookies will have a negative impact upon the usability of many
                                websites.
                                9.3. If you block cookies, you will not be able to use all the features on our website.
                            </p>
                        </li>
</ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is main.css

```
.heading-li {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.paragraph {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Use `@media()` queries to add CSS rules based on properties of the browser's viewport.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change CSS of website if accessed through a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838127/how-to-change-css-of-website-if-accessed-through-a-mobile-browser)

Comment: Why is there a class of "mobile" in some elements? That's not a Bootstrap class...

Comment: "responsive" means you expect the layout to work well in different size screens But "working well" is subjective. How specifically do you want it to respond to a different screen size differently than it does now?

Answer (score 1):

I checked the output of your code. It's responsive.

I suggest you read about the concept. It seems you do not know what the term "responsive" means.

Simply, it means **there is no horizontal scroll bar** when viewed in any screen width, mainly, a laptop, a tablet and a mobile phone and bigger and smaller.

For visual and conceptual explanations, see:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp

Comment: Hi @Shadi Namrouti But when I check output in mobile screen why red color is not applying to all mobile screen ?

Comment: And which mobile browser did you test on to conclude it did not work for you?

Comment: @Clone -- Bootstrap bg-danger means red background. Please look up Bootstrap definitions before commenting.

Answer (score 0):

To make it responsive use @media only screen max-width(600px)
and set your all elements size according to this screen size, but i suggest here don't use px, use here rem value because it sets automatically according to your screen.

Comment: Why 600? What value of rem? How does this help the original question?